# resolution of image for t-shirt design

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to draw a lady that will get printed on a t-shirt. The lady will be positioned around the heart and will be around that size, so just a lady on the center of the chest. What size should i make the file where i will draw in Photoshop. What resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with the t-shirt design for a long time (about 20 years).

The minimum resolution used is 300ppi (or dpi) for screen printing.

Sometimes when I have to use reticulation for the print screen I change the resolution to 400 or 600ppi for small designs.

That is the way I work and some of my work colleagues too.